# Header Pin Configuration on Pi Zero

Tags: hardware

I need to wire up 3-5 (maybe a few more) Pi Zeros for a monitoring project that will only require I2C so I only need pins 1,3,5,9 or 3,4,5,6. I can go either 3v or 5v. I want to minimize soldering and think about just adding headers to these locations. Would one configuration be better than the other from a flexibility standpoint? I lean towards a 2x3 header config on pins 1-6 mainly since adding just pins 1 and 2 later if needed for something else seems like a pain. This is more about a time savings than anything else but am I missing a reduced header pin configuration that might give me more flexibility in the future?

Comment: Well, from a flexibility standpoint I would add a full 40 pin header, I doubt the savings in component cost and time are worth any trouble further down the road.

Answer (score 3):

I would just install a 2x3 or 2x5 header on pins 1-6(10)

Then if you need the full 40 pins you can just add a 2x17 or 2x15 header to fill out the full 40 pins.

The advantage of the smaller header is that it is easier to use a 2x3 or 2x5 [ribbon cable crimp connector](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10651) since you won't have the extra pins in your way.